# Sorting an array with AnyObjects in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting, dictionary, swift

I have an array being extracted from a dictionary with `.allKeys` and I would like to sort it using the `sorted()` function like this

```
func order(s1: Int, s2: Int) -> Bool {
        return s1 < s2
    }
let array = sorted(dictionary.allKeys, order)
```

However, the type `.allKeys` yields is AnyObject and I get an error since I used Int in my `order()` function. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you declaring `dictionary`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let arraySorted = dictionary.allKeys.sorted() { ($0 as Int) < ($1 as Int) }
```

is more concise and should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let array = sorted(dictionary.allKeys as Array<Int>, order)
```